# Button element not interactable

Tags: python-3.x, xml, selenium-webdriver, button, element

I've been building an automated checkout script in Python 3.8 for the following website https://fasttimes.com.au/ (site built using Magento) and all buttons, drop downs, inputs etc have functioned up until this point. At the shipping selection stage however the button responsible for saving shipping details and allowing proceeding to billing stage, according to the python console reads; "Message: element not interactable".

I have tried using `execute_script` to directly interact with the site, this does not yield an error and says it's completed, but within the WebDriver the button hasn't actually been clicked and so proceedings to the next step of checkout do not take place. As for 'Action Chains'. they simply yield the error above, same as finding by `XPATH` or `CSS_Selector`. I've tried using the import 'Keys' and attempting to action the button with the ENTER key, as well as using the WebDriver substitute `.send_keys(u'\ue007')` to no avail. Before it's mentioned below I've also tried using waits, however maybe I'm doing them wrong?

E.g

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(
ec.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login:guest")))
```

Correct me if above line is incorrect formatting

Site's HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
    <p class="back-link"><a href="#" onclick="checkout.back(); return false;"><small>« </small>Back</a></p>
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
    <span id="shipping-method-please-wait" class="please-wait" style="display:none;">
        <img src="https://static.fasttimes.com.au/skin/frontend/ultimo/default/images/opc-ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading next step..." title="Loading next step..." class="v-middle"> Loading next step...        </span>
</div>
```

My current code is:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button").send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I believe the button that I'm trying to interact with is

```
<button type="button" class="button" onclick="shippingMethod.save()"><span><span>Continue</span></span></button>
```

...but I'm not too sure. I feel like I've at this point exhausted all possible avenues, but I refuse to believe this damned button isn't intractable! Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned you want to proceed to *Billing* stage, I understand you are at step 1 of the checkout process. Am saying this because what you have identified with `xpath //*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button` is the button at *step 4 Shipping Method*, which is indeed not intractable yet.

You need to select the Checkout Method first, and carry on from there. Give this a try:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('login:guest').click()  # select the "Checkout as Guest" radio button
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='onepage-guest-register-button']")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='onepage-guest-register-button']").click()  # click Continue
```

Alternatively, if it's step 4 you're really stuck at:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button")))
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='shipping-method-buttons-container']/button").click()
```